# How to save captured image only into a folder created by me, and not DCIM folder

Tags: android

I am using the native Android camera in my application and save images to my custom folder created by me programatically, but at the same time it also saved in DCIM folder of android. I donot want to savedin DCIM folder,or I want to delete it from DCIM Folder programatically. How to do this.I am new in android developer.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what you mean by "using the native Android camera". For example, you could edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are "using the native Android camera" and how you "ave images to my custom folder created by me programatically".

Comment: I am capturing image through intent and saving in internal storage, but at that time it also saved in DCIM folder,so I donot want to saved in DCIM folder,or I want to delete it from DCIM Folder programatically

Comment: Do you mean an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`? Do you mean something else?

Comment: yes ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` has little to do with "the native Android camera".

By using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you are delegating your request to an arbitrary third-party application. Dozens, if not hundreds, of *different* `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`-capable apps ship pre-installed on the thousands of Android device models. Users are also welcome to install other apps that offer `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activities.

Any of them can do whatever they want.

Ideally, if you specify `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, the third-party camera app will write the photo only to the location that you specify in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. However, third-party apps can do whatever they want.

> I donot want to saved in DCIM folder

The user's chosen `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity can do whatever it wants. You do not get a vote. So, if the activity wants to save a copy of the photo to some other location, it is welcome to do so.

> I want to delete it from DCIM Folder programatically

You have no reliable way to know if the user's chosen `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity has saved a second copy of the photo, and you may not have permission to delete it. For all you know, the user's chosen `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity will upload the image to a server somewhere.

Your choices are:

- Ignore all of this
- Stop using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, either by:

  - Not capturing photos
  - Using the camera APIs (e.g., `android.hardware.Camera`) directly
  - Using [a third-party camera library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created)